# Why will the Ag-Grid-Material Icons not work?

Tags: angular, sass, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using the the material theme of Ag-Grid with custom variables as described in the documentation. Everythings is working fine but instead of the icons only a square will be displayed:
[image]
If you look in the inspector of chrome the right font-family is set:
[image]
So has anybody a solution/workaround for my problem?

Comment: What is the icon you are not seeing? Can you share some code snippets? If possible create a minimal reproducible app in Stackblitz.

Comment: This should be asc order icon. The the header is a default one only with a text '#'. I have researched that the font-family will be loaded in a scss file. Can I check that anywhere in the chrome inspector? Code Snippet isn't possible because to rebuild the project structure isn't possible(big project which will be migrated from AngularJS to Angular 8 -> we use gulp as a task runner).

Comment: Are you sure that you have imported the agGridMaterialFont.css (or scss file for that matter) from node_modules?

Comment: Your font is likely not loading properly. Check in Chrome's Developer Tools, Network panel, Font tab.

Comment: The font will be loaded with @font-face in a scss file. Should this also be visible in the dev tools?

Answer (score 0):

In Mycase, i had to use font-feature-settings: 'liga'.

source: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/536#issuecomment-432227513

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.